# How to build a Firefox extension that open like firebug

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I know that this is not easy to achieve, however there would be a way to do so as firebug does...

I want to build firefox extension like firebug that open in popup. How to build such extension that open it.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

- It is standard [XUL Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Creating_a_Window)
- You can check firebug source code from .xpi file (content/firebug/firefox/firebug.xul and firebugFrame.xul)

  - xpi file (which is standard zip file) is located in [profile folder's](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) extension directory